# C program duplicating string on failing a condition (if)

Tags: c

The string "**type a character**" is repeated twice after failing the condition(if) **a[0] != 'q'**. I need to know why it is happening and how can I solve it!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
char a[1]="";
here:
puts("type a character");
scanf("%c",&a[0]);
if(a[0] != 'q'){
    puts("try again");
    goto here;
}
if(a[0] == 'q') {
    puts("successful");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: i had tried implementing it with 'while' and 'do while' loops too. but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%c");` reads the newline character from the `ENTER` key. When you type a char `a`, you type `a` followed by `ENTER` key too. Now there are two chars in the input buffer. Since the newline char is still in the input buffer, you get the string `type a character` two times.

Its suggested not to use scanf, and reasons are stated here [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Alternatively you can use,

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

to read the character & getting rid of newline.

Comment: thanks for the link. i needed to read about it rather than get a solution.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf("%c", ...)` will read any character from the input, including a newline character. So if you press `a<enter>b<enter>`, the first `scanf` will get `'a'`, the second will get a newline character, and the third will get `'b'`.

In your case, the second time `scanf` is called, it will immediately return with a newline, which will then cause the loop to execute a third time.

One way to fix this is to add a space before the `%c`: `scanf(" %c", ...)`. This will cause `scanf` to skip all whitespace (including newlines) before reading the character.

Comment: but isn't this just a hack? is there a more elegant rework available without the use of functions

Comment: @ShouryaSharma Why do you think it's a hack? And what do you mean by "without the use of functions"? `scanf` is a function and you were already using it...

Comment: i meant customized functions or self made ones. i think of it as a hack coz i'm a web developer learning C and I thought the solution would be quite simple and my code looked quite obvious and direct. idk what gcc is thinking, as i didnt dive deep

Comment: @ShouryaSharma Then what do you mean by "customized functions"? This is a legitimate use of `scanf`, which is a standard function. Where did I say anything about creating a new function?

Comment: @ShouryaSharma I explained in my answer exactly why your code didn't work. And I don't know how you expect a solution that is more simple than adding a single space to your code.

Comment: yes, you're correct! its not a hack but its C and its complications

Comment: your approach is not working when i compile and run it in cmd using gcc

Comment: @ShouryaSharma My approach works just fine ([example](https://ideone.com/X8FyC5)).